# Ubuntu 16.04 Server credentials for VMWare VM image

Tags: 16.04, server, vmware

I've downloaded the Ubuntu server:

```
ubuntu-16.04-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.vmdk
```

from this site:

https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/16.04/release/

Now its running on my VMWare Workstation.
[image]

I've looking for the **user** and **password** with no luck.

whats's the "default" user-pass and "sudo" "root" credentials.-

Thanks in advance

Comment: No. ubuntu user, doesn't work